# Javascript/jQuery: mouseenter event not firing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a code like this

```
$('#singleColumn' + time).show(SHOW_COMPONENT_SPEED)
    .live('mouseenter', function() { $('#propertiesButtonSingle' + time).fadeIn(FADEIN_SPEED); })
    .live('mouseleave', function() { $('#propertiesButtonSingle' + time).fadeOut(FADEOUT_SPEED); });
```

which I'm using to show/hide a button when mouseenter/mouseleave events are fired on a box.

The problem is that my page is dynamic, i.e. I keep adding new HTML to the page using JQuery .html() function. What happes is that the mouse events are fired only for the last box I added (I add them by drag and dropping): pratically it works fine for the first box, if I add a second one the events are fired correctly for it but when I move the mouse over the first box nothing happens. If I add a third box the second one stops working too, etc...

The code I posted is for one kind of box, but for the other types it is pratically the same apart from the selector names.

Comment: What is `time`, and is this run for each possible selector?

Comment: time is a timestamp to make different IDs for each object. 
This code gets executed when a box is created, so the selector is the name of the box which has just been created, what do you mean by every possibile selector?

Comment: To everyone: it is just like the new mouseenter events overwrites all the previous ones even if the selector is different.

Comment: Any chance that you're reusing the same `time` variable for all the timestamp references? If so, the handlers will only reference the most recent value of that variable.

Comment: I checked this too, and the timestamp is different every time.

Comment: a test page would help us a lot, anyway have you tried binding these events (without `live` ) whenever you add a new `SingleColumn` element?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at .delegate() - http://api.jquery.com/delegate

you could bind events to an object higher up the DOM tree and listen ...

Comment: But in this case the object is not higher up the DOM tree, because I only attach the handler to the object after the object has been created.